# GameObject selection within bounding area(Seleting gameObject in general direction via transform comparing)

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to cast a ray / sphere from a vector(origin) which is inside of a BoxCollider bound and limit its maxDistance so that it won't exceed the bound area and hit only the objects inside this bound with layerMask. How does one achieve this?

Also, if I cast this as a sphereCast and multiple objects were hit how could I get only the object nearest to the center of the sphereCast? I've searched around for quite a while, but couldn't quite get it there.

Edit #1

[image: Example]

While I thank you for the previous answers I update this edit for a better elaboration of what I really want to achieve.

When I asked you the initial question it was still vague for me how to resolve the missing rayCast / sphereCast which I do not want either which will eventually miss depending on the size of target / sphereCast radius.

The end goal is to have directional input to select a gameObject and never miss.  I already have this bounding box collecting transforms of gameObjects within in a List, and if I input with say gamepad analog stick giving normalized direction I wanted to choose the one in that general direction. However, I'm aware if I do it in just rayCast / sphereCast I'd have to do multiple casting per input to ensure not missing a target which I thought would be an unnecessary block of code. The ideal thing would be: if normalized input dir: vector2(1,0, 0) the purple target on 2 O'clock position from the origin would be selected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the closest to the Center you could get the hit colliders’ transforms and loop through them subtracting the position from the Center. Then pick out the minimum magnitude. You could use magnitude squared to improve performance.

As for only picking things inside a box collider, one way would be to use a spherecast of radius equal to the largest dimension of the box. This will reach outside the box too, but is guaranteed to get everything inside the box. Then you could manually check to see if they are inside the box collider using traditional collision checks.

Answer (score 0):

1:

I would suggest, have a look at [`Physics.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)

as it is perfect for your situation:

> Find all colliders touching or inside of the given box.

You can pass in your box collider's center and size as parameters, this will return an array of overlapping (hit) colliders and you can use the first one.

2:

If you still want to use SphereCast, it populates [`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) object which has the first object that is hit in `collider` property

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Collider as your Bounds, you can simply use `Collider.bounds.extents` or `Collider.bounds.size` to get the size of your collider and then (according to your starting position) set the max Size for your Spherecast. E.g. if your SphereCast starts in the middle of a Cube you just use one of the values from `Collider.bounds.extents` as your max size.

For the second question:
`Physics.SphereCastAll` will return an array of [RaycastHits](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html). These have a property `distance` which returns the distance from your raycasts origin to the point where the collider was hit. You can simply iterate over the array and use the object with the smallest distance to get the nearest one.

Also I think `Physics.SphereCast` should return the first object that was hit (so therefore the nearest one), if that is all you want to get. But I'm not sure right now if this always behaves like you want it to, but it might be worth testing as it would be way better for your performance than using the `Physics.SphereCastAll` method.